# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'life'

Tags: python, ооп

[image: Мой код на картинке]

Выводит ошибку при выполнении цикла:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'life'

В моем классе и обьектах есть же "life". В чем проблема?

Comment: Вы перезаписали `man` на `input(...)` выше цикла.

Comment: вставляйте код текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 2):

У вас в строке man = input("...") происходит переназначение класса с именем man результатом функции input. Поменяйте либо название класса (лучше сделать с заглавной буквы), либо поменяйте название переменной в строке man = input("").

В цикле у вас тоже проблема, в строке shot = man.kill вы что хотите сделать? Сейчас вы пытаетесь обратиться к члену kill класса man, который у вас не задан.

Если я вас правильно понял, то должно быть примерно так:

```
from random import randrange

class Man:    
    def __init__(self, life, armor, kill):
        self.life = life
        self.armor = armor
        self.kill = kill


fool = Man(100, 20, 25)
dude = Man(100, 80, 50)
noob = Man(100, 60, 65)

mans = {'fool': fool,
        'dude': dude,
        'noob': noob}

choice = input("What man you want choose for fight?!\n"
            "Answer fool, dude or noob!")

if choice not in mans:
    print("Incorrect answer.")
else:
    print("Ok! You choice is " + choice)

    print("Fight begin")

    man = mans[choice]

    while man.life >= 0:
        wound = randrange(50, 100)
        man.armor -= wound
        man.life -= wound
```

Comment: У вас очень странные методы is_armor и is_kill. Методы начинающиеся с is, обычно возвращают значение, но не устанавливают его. Например is_alive, возвращает True если объект работает, или False если объект завершил работу.